# Android 7 (?) ignoring timeout in BluetoothServerSocket.accept

Tags: android, bluetooth

When I call [`BluetoothServerSocket.accept(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothServerSocket.html#accept(int)) with some timeout value, my Alcatel A30 running Android 7.0 just ignores the timeout and blocks forever. Is this a new bug in Android or some stupidity with this particular phone?

Here's a simple code-section to demonstrate the problem (just paste this into any activity and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />` to your manifest):

```
Thread test = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Getting Bluetooth adapter...");
            BluetoothAdapter bt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            System.out.println("Registering service profile...");
            BluetoothServerSocket server = bt.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord
                ("Test", UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

            System.out.println("Accepting connection with timeout...");
            server.accept(1000);  // Android 7.0 gets stuck here rather than timing out

            System.out.println("Accepted!");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Got an error:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

test.setDaemon(true);
test.start();
```

Expected output (from any of my older Android devices; exception shows up after 1s):

```
Getting Bluetooth adapter...
Registering service profile...
Accepting connection with timeout...
Got an error:
java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.acceptNative(Native Method)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.accept(BluetoothSocket.java:364)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket.accept(BluetoothServerSocket.java:113)
    at line containing server.accept(1000);
```

Output from my Android 7.0 Alcatel A30:

```
Getting Bluetooth adapter...
Registering service profile...
Accepting connection with timeout...
```

And then it sits there until I kill the app or until I actually connect to the service, in which case I get

```
`Accepted!`
```

even after many minutes of waiting before I connect.

***Update:***

*It seems like the code-sample is maybe creating some confusion (Re: deleted answer). Usually when someone posts an exception on SO, they are looking for help how to fix it. This is **not** what I'm after. By setting the timeout and then not connecting, I am explicitly asking for the exception. The problem is that I am **not** getting the exception on my Android 7.0 device.*

Comment: Would you please post your code snippet that includes the connection establishment thread?

Comment: @UddhavGautam Done.

Comment: A, Bluetooth problem comes in every OS (even in Ubuntu, Windows, Android everywhere). I tried to understand the problem. Please update your feedbacks so that, again, I can try next time.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a device that's running with Android 7.0.
Other devices (Android 8 and 9) have the expected behavior : a IOException is raised when the accept did not get an incoming connection within its configured timeout.

What I ended up doing (and it's not very pretty) is using a Timer to close the BluetoothServerSocket from another thread, this caused accept to raise the IOException as though it was a timeout.

```
BluetoothServerSocket mBssOutCom = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("blabla", uuid);
Timer securityTimer = new Timer();
try {
    //! there seems to be a bug in android 7.0
    //! that makes the connect timeout never fire. This timer will do the dirty trick
    //! Should only have an effect if the bug is active
    securityTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this code will be executed after 2 seconds
            if (mBssOutCom != null) {
                try {
                    mBssOutCom.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBssOutCom = null;
            }
        }
    }, 1500);
    socketCom = mBssOutCom.accept(1000);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "tryToConnect: accept timedOut");
}
securityTimer.cancel();

if (mBssOutCom != null) {
    mBssOutCom.close();
    mBssOutCom = null;
}
```

If anyone is aware of a better solution, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the timeout isn't used when accepting connections. It is used as the timeout when sending or receiving data through the socket (after the connection has been made).

Calling `BluetoothServerSocket.accept(...)` with a timeout ends up calling the `setOption(...)` in [LocalSocketImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/oreo-release/core/java/android/net/LocalSocketImpl.java) with `SocketOptions.SO_TIMEOUT`, which in turn uses [setsockopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setsockopt) to set:

> **SO_RCVTIMEO:** Sets the timeout value that specifies the maximum amount of time an input function waits until it completes. ... If a receive operation has blocked for this much time without receiving additional data, it shall return with a partial count or errno set to [EAGAIN] or [EWOULDBLOCK] if no data is received.
>
> **SO_SNDTIMEO:** Sets the timeout value specifying the amount of time that an output function blocks because flow control prevents data from being sent. If a send operation has blocked for this time, it shall return with a partial count or with errno set to [EAGAIN] or [EWOULDBLOCK] if no data is sent.